# Load Nested Parquet file in Pig?

Tags: apache-pig, parquet

A parquet file is created from an Avro file. Now I need to load the Parquet file in Pig. Following is the schema I got from `parquet-tools schema` command.

```
  message Logs {
  optional group SUPER1 {
    optional group FIELD1 (LIST) {
      repeated int32 array;
    }
    optional group FIELD2 (LIST) {
      repeated int32 array;
    }
  }
  optional group SUPER2 {
    optional int32 FIELD1;
    optional binary FIELD2 (UTF8);
    optional double FIELD3;
    optional int32 FIELD4;
    optional double FIELD5;
    optional binary FIELD6 (UTF8);
  }
  optional group SUPER3 {
    required int32 FIELD1;
    required int32 FIELD2;
    optional binary FIELD3 (UTF8);
    optional binary FIELD4 (UTF8);
  }
  required binary SUPER4 (UTF8);
  optional binary SUPER5 (UTF8);
 }
```

Now I am not able to understand the equivalent pig schema to load this file. I am using `parquet.pig.ParquetLoader`. I did the following transformations:-

1. array would be loaded as `chararray`
2. how to load nested data? bid_info.creative_id is not working: `mismatched input '.' expecting RIGHT_PAREN`
3. I am loading all the fields, whether optional or not. Optional values should be loaded as null in Pig.

I also tried using simple loading without any explicit schema then I got this error:

```
Failed to parse: Invalid list type optional group FIELD1 (LIST) {
  repeated int32 array;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to access is to use `.` operator as showed in point-2 of the question. It didn't work from me because I was using `parquet.pig.ParquetLoader()`. Parquet for pig now has been adopted by Apache and has the maximum support so I used jars from [maven](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.parquet) and used `org.apache.parquet.pig.ParquetLoader()` as the parser. Following code worked:-

```
log_parquet = LOAD 'logs' USING org.apache.parquet.pig.ParquetLoader();
```

req_parquet will be a tuple containing 5 fields (Super1-5). Fields Super1,2,3 itself is the tuple. `Super1.Field1` and `Super1.Field2` itself is a bag of tuples, where each element in the array is tuple.

It is quite complex, but worked for me.